# DIsplay data from from server in sliding tabs

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am creating a new application in which i will be having 2 sliding tabs.Both the tabs will have a list view.The list view will have have images and text.The data from the list will be coming from the server in json format.Now my query is how will i show this data in to the list. As in how will i load the data in both the tabs simultaneously.I dont want progress bar to be shown when user swipes to other tab.Please suggest me some details.

Comment: Are you loading different data for both tabs or do they contain the same data?

Comment: same data but there will be a feild say int, and depending whather its 0 or 1 data will be displayed in the tabs

Comment: Are you using fragments? If so load the data in your activity, which will have the progress bar and then create your fragments after that.